# Unable to get Magento 2 Media URL in Model\Config\Source file

Tags: magento2, layout, base-url

I want to display images as radio button option in Magento 2 Admin panel Store Configuration.

For this i have added the following code in `etc/adminhtml/system.xml` file:

```
<field id="mymodsettings_imagepattern" translate="label" type="radios" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Select One of the Image</label>
    <source_model>Mynamespace\Mymodule\Model\Config\Source\Displayimageoptions</source_model>
</field>
```

Also I created a file `Displayimageoptions.php` in `Mynamespace\Mymodule\Model\Config\Source\` directory with the below code:

```
<?php
namespace Mynamespace\Mymodule\Model\Config\Source;

class Displayimageoptions implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

        return [['value' => 1, 'label' => __("<img src='" . $mediaUrl . "mymod/images/pattern_1.png' />")]];
    }

}
```

I am unable to get the media URL here. When tried to print $this, it returns empty object. I also tried the below codes but did not get to work for me:

```
$this->getUrl($route, $params)
$this->_helper->getUrl($route, $params)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the media url using the following code:

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
$mediaUrl = $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```